# SQL Server 2008 R2: Query MS Access from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, sql-server-2008-r2

Want to retrieve records from Access through linked server in SQL Server and need to convert/cast the column with `VARCHAR` for some constraint.

My attempt:

```
SELECT Cola, Colb
FROM MSAccess_LinkedServer...TableName  
WHERE CAST([Cola] AS VARCHAR) = 'A123'
```

Unable to get the result from above query.

But when I remove `CAST` then I will get the result, but I want to know how to put the  `cast/convert`.

Comment: Please try to provide a [mcve]. What do you mean with _Unable to get the result_? Are there any errors?

Comment: There is no error, just getting column name's but no records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No casting should be needed for text. How about simply:

```
WHERE [Cola] = 'A123'
```

Comment: Columns in the `WHERE` clause are not fixed and so values, we need to convert them.

Comment: Field names are fixed. If you wish to modify which fields are used in a Where clause, you must rewrite the SQL.